# Can't access content in hovered div

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup:

```css
    .container .option {
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      background-color: gray;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .container:hover .option {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="card">
          <p>Hover here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <label>Option 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <label>Option 2</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        Other content
      </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AbLUqAkMT9DyJqr0D1oc?p=preview

If I have `position:absolute` on the `.container .option` selector, the hovered content correctly floats over the 'other content' div. However then I can't access the checkboxes in the hovered div. If I remove `position:absolute` I can access the checkboxes but the content doesn't float properly.

Comment: that's currently correct?  it looks like "option 2" also covers "option 1"... you want that to happen??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2p1awoam/ looking something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change a little bit markup and styles as showed here:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
      <p>Hover here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="popup">
      <div class="option">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
        <label>Option 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
          <input type="checkbox"/>
          <label>Option 2</label>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Other content
</div>

.container {
  position:relative;
}
.container .popup {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container:hover .popup {
  display: block;
  left:0px;
  top:100%;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/BsRDdVCM27AQr7TeRoui?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achive

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="card">
          <p>Hover here</p>
      </div>
          <div class="option">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <label>Option 1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="option">
              <input type="checkbox"/>
              <label>Option 2</label>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
      Other content
    </div>

.container .option {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  top: 0;
}

.container:hover .option {
  display: block;
}

.other{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/2Ei8oE0aadOqifkatyR7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me this solution is much cleaner, because

- one can click the labels (which can also be archived with for=name)
- it actually uses the .card-class which is otherwise useless
- it is shorter and easier to understand
- the positioning of the popup can be controlled by copy and pasting the text above or below the menu, which class name is 'hoverme' here
- to have an extra div for the menu as a whole allows the elements inside to respect their sizes and align like expected.

```css
      .container>.card .hoverme
      {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        background:#ccc;
      }
      
      .container>.card:hover .hoverme
      {
        display:inline;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="hoverme">
      <div class="option">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>
          Option 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>
          Option 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Hover here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Other content
</div>
```